# Resize On-Screen Android Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, resize

I'm developing an application which requires that the softKeyboard from Android to be resized to a specific width and height. Is there a way to do this from XML or using the activity class itself? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: I see. Is there an alternative solution in achieving a similar result? I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: maybe disable the android keyboard and create your own?

Comment: Okay, I finally disabled the android keyboard. Is there a more efficient way in re-creating the keyboard rather than adding a layout containing buttons with their respective values?

Comment: I would assume the easiest way would be to use a KeyboardView.
These links may be helpful:
http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html